# Changing UICollectionView properties programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to achieve this, I have a `UICollectionView` and a `UITextView` inside it's cell, and I hate constraints so I went straight to my code editor to achieve this.

For example; we have bigger screen devices, I want to modify my `UICollectionViewCell` to fit the `UICollectionView`, So I did it, but I also want to update my textView's frame and etc

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! WordsMainCollectionViewCell
    cell.userWord.textColor = UIColor.red // test
    return CGSize(width: myCollectionView.frame.width, height:  myCollectionView.frame.height);
}
```

Just to see if my code works, I used `cell.userWord.textColor = UIColor.red` but it didn't work, when I run the app it crashes and gives this error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is there any ways to access my cell once a startup?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are retrieving a WordsMainCollectionViewCell? Could you replace `let cell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! WordsMainCollectionViewCell` by `if let cell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as?
 WordsMainCollectionViewCell { ...`? Maybe you forgot to register your cell type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the right code, but not in the right place..

You also have your `WordsMainCollectionViewCell.swift` file, So do your updating work on `awakeFromNib`

```
class WordsMainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var userWord: UITextView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.userWord.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: @user9119326, but you shouldn't. Collection cell's frame should be handled by `UICollectionViewLayout` instance assigned to your `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @user28434,there’s hundreds of ways when it comes to code

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar, you really shouldn't change **cell**'s frame not via layout delegate. Unless you want collection view to look and behave, let's say, unpredictable. You better use some layout delegate's method, like [this for FlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview).

Comment: I am not using it, I don’t like these ways— I love complex coding, thanks by the way